# Generating data for one-class dataset

Tags: dataset, synthetic-data, one-class, data-generating-process

In case I have a dataset that have only one class unlabeled (benign), could you please list some algorithms/papers that are used to generate complementary data (malignant) based on benign data only? I know SMOTE is there, but it's used in to generate data that is already labeled.

Comment: So you have data for only one category and you want to use it for generating data for the missing category?

Comment: @Tim. Yeah exactly. I just have one category. So I would like to generate data that is not like the one category that I have. The dataset is not labelled and has only data for one category. I would like to treat the problem as anomaly detection where anything that is not like my dataset is abnormal. But I am not sure yet what papers algorithms I can use to generate data for the other category (abnormal for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just have one category. So I would like to generate data that is not
> like the one category that I have. The dataset is not labelled and has
> only data for one category. I would like to treat the problem as
> anomaly detection where anything that is not like my dataset is
> abnormal. But I am not sure yet what papers algorithms I can use to
> generate data for the other category (abnormal for example).

Imagine that your known category is pictures of humans and you want to generate pictures of non-humans. So you have to generate pictures of chimpanzees, dogs, cats, airplanes, tractors, atomic bombs, trees, planets, hamburgers, dinosaurs, screenshots of SlackOverflow.com page, hammers, hamsters, rivers, chairs, ... and an infinite number of every other thing that is not-human. Even worse if you want to generate those images from your data consisting of images of humans, how would you generate an image of an atomic bomb knowing only how humans look like? This simply cannot be done.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I forgot to add that dataset is timeseries.

Comment: @Abraheem this doesn't change much.

Comment: Thank you. So how does one-class algorithms work like OneSVM that creates a decision surface for one class and treat anything that is not within this boundary as outlier? I just want to know please if I can find similar models if you know any.

Comment: @Abraheem anomaly detection algorithms learn the distribution of the known class and classify everything that does not "look" like the known class as an anomaly. So they use the data that you have, rather than the data that you don't have.

Comment: You mean they have more than one class in their dataset not only one category that is unlabeled as in my case?

Comment: @Abraheem no, they have only one class.

Comment: Thank you. You mean, it's not possible to data that I don't have based on data that I have? What if I just want to create anything that does not look like what I have? Are there models of this kind please or the answer is still know even though we restrained what we want to generate?

Comment: @Abraheem you can. You can, for example, generate a uniformly distributed random noise and train a classifier to distinguish between your time-series and the random noise, but then if you apply the classifier to *whatever else* then your data or uniformly distributed random noise, it would be a lottery on what it predicts, because it only knows the two categories of data.